# Codova Camera plugin doesn't work in Android (Ionic Framework)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

Last plugin version. iOS works fine, when try to open camera/gallery on Android - nothing happens both in devices and emulator (no matter what version).

```
 $scope.takePhoto = function () {
        var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 217,
            targetHeight: 217,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };
```

Tried to remove and add plugin and thats doesnt help, also tried to change permissions, thats doesnd help tho... What shout I do? 
Should say again that at iOS it works like a charm...

Comment: are you able to invoke camera in your mobile

Comment: Yes, I tested both iOS and Android. In iPhone that's work, in Samsung Galaxy S5 and couple devices in emulator - doesn't...

Comment: can you provide your code in plunker or jsfidel

Comment: Why? In browser it's not work as usual simply because browser don't have camera...

Comment: hahaha, yes you are right but i have worked with camera plugin for many times may be i can find any error on seeing your code. also only providing option variable in camera invoking option does not help or solve your problem you should provide some more details there is a chance of your side mistake

Comment: ok, give me 10 minutes :)

Comment: There. In brief - https://plnkr.co/edit/EM12r5d4w331OjR2ITm5?p=preview I didnt ever use plunker before, tell me please if there is something wrong. Hope its ok. Camera code and link to scope function are the same.

Comment: @JerryBrauberg I dont see cordova.js script file inclusion in your HTML code. Is this the complete code?

Comment: In project I have cordova. Just forget to insert in plunker. As I said, in iOS its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by a thousands experiments. Dont remember why, but i had `<script> window.cordova = {};</script>` in index.html. I removed it and that's it - camera works.

All that I want to know, if there is someone who know for what reason could be needed this line - explain me, please, maybe I lost something in my app now... :)